# Saving and accessing a variable from a separate class

Tags: ios, class, sprite-kit

I'm working in Xcode using `Spritekit` and I'm struggling to build a separate class to display **high scores**.

Level 1 has a property called `highscore`(`@synthesize highscor = highscore;`) as its name suggests, records the highest scores, but I can't figure out how to send it to the high score class.

```
 JKGLevel1 *class1Instance = [[JKGLevel1 alloc] init];
 int x = class1Instance.highscor;
```

That's how I tried it, but when I leave level 1 and go to the high score class, it keeps telling me that the high score is 0.

Comment: The reason it's always 0 is because the instance you have on screen is not the same one you created with alloc init. This is a classic newbie mistake that I see in multiple questions every day. If you don't know how to get references to the controllers you've created, then you'll be absolutely lost as an iOS programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you do not need to @sythesize anything anymore, but thats just an aside. What you will need to do is create a singleton class, i.e.: a class with properties that are only instantiated once and can be accessed ANYWHERE in you code where you please.

For example I use this for storing account information :

**In the .m file**

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
static AppManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
return [super init];
}
```

**in the .h file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>

@interface AppManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) ACAccount *twitterAccount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayOfAccounts;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

**Then in any file I want to use this : **

```
AppManager *sharedManager;
sharedManager = [AppManager sharedManager];

NSString *usrName = sharedManager.twitterAccount.username;
```

Hope this actually helps you. There are also other ways you can do this by just creating a class that you manage carefully without this singleton nonsense, but this is a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

1. In your `HighScoreClass` make a property named `lavel1HighScore`. (if you don't want to make property for each level then you can do it by an array. :) )
2. When your level 1 is complete pass the highScore of level1 to that property of HighScoreClass.

Like:

```
JKGLevel1 *class1Instance = [[JKGLevel1 alloc] init];
HighScoreClass *highScore = [[HighScoreClass alloc] init];
highScore.lavel1HighScore = class1Instance.highscor;
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the scores in a plist to be read in viewdidload or if there is a reason to pass a live score object from level to level -

I would suggest that you put in your scores in a separate class (just an ordinary class with a header and method (.h & .m) and just make the class available to all your levels (class)  this can easily be done via the following code:

... levelx.h

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  @class Class_scores;

  @interface LevelxViewController : UIViewController <> {
 }
  @property (nonatomic, strong) Class_scores *highscore_class;
```

needless to say you will need to define a function in the (high_score) class to return the high score and call it from your level class.